# i am getting error of "no mathing function for call to ". give me the solution

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std ;


class studentpersonal{

    protected :

        int rollno ,age ;
        string name , sex;

        public:

            studentpersonal(int rollno, int age , string name, string gender)
            {

                cout<<"NAME IS  : "<<name;
                cout<<"\nID IS  : "<<rollno;
                cout<<"\nAGE IS  : "<<age;
                cout<<"\nGENDER IS  : "<<gender;


            }



};


class studentmarks : public studentpersonal{

    public:

    studentmarks(int mark1 , int mark2 ,int mark3, int mark4 )
    {
        /*cout<<"marks 1  "<<mark1;
        cout<<"marks 2  "<<mark2;
        cout<<"marks 3  "<<mark3;
        cout<<"marks 4  "<<mark3 ;*/
    }
};

main(){

        studentpersonal ob(6709,19,"WASSAUF","MALE");
    studentmarks ob1(90,95,97,91);

}
```

getting an error of no function for call to , what should i do ??

Comment: Putting an imperative "give me the solution" in your title is really not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Class studentpersonal does not have the default constructor. However the constructor of class studentmarks that is a derived class of class  studentpersonal tries to call the default constructor of class studentpersonal.

Becuase the compiler can not find the default constructor then it issues an error.

There is no any sense to make class studentmarks as a derived class of studentpersonal. You could simply declare an array within class studentpersonal that had marks of a student.